# Azure Function BlobTrigger - BlobScaninfo missing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I understand that when using an Azure Function Blob trigger it is possible to rerun a trigger by either removing the blob receipt in the blob container `azure-webjobs-host` folder `blobreceipts`.

Or it's also possible to update the LastScan date or remove the blobscaninfo folder entirely to re-run all blob triggers.

`blobscaninfo/functionAppName/storageAccount/storageContainer` –> scanInfo –> {"LatestScan":"date"}

[image]

My question is whether the blobscaninfo folder should be regenerated if it's deleted, or if there are situations where the folder doesn't exist at all. I may have remove it previously, but can't actually remember, the function trigger is working as expected, but I would like to rerun some of the triggers again and was expecting the blobscaninfo folder/files to be there.

[image]

Can someone explain if this file is optional and what the expected behaviour is if it's deleted? Or whether perhaps there is some sort of other reason the folder wouldn't be there?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, The Azure Functions runtime creates the blobscaninfo folder, which is optional and its not a compulsion for that folder to exist to make your blob trigger run, It is used to keep details about the most recent scan of the blob container. When the function is called again after blobscaninfo folder is destroyed, the folder will be created again. You can manually remove the blob receipt for a given blob from the azure-webjobs-hosts container if you wish to force a reprocessing of that blob. Reprocessing will undoubtedly happen at a later time, even though it might not happen right away. The scaninfo blob in azure-webjobs-hosts/blobscaninfo can be changed to reprocess instantly. The LatestScan attribute causes all blobs to be updated with last updated timestamp after it to undergoes a second scan.

Also, Refer this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429797/azure-web-job-blobtrigger-reset-scaninfo-to-trigger-function-for-existing-blob) by **Ivan glasenberg** to reprocess the previously added blobs by removing the scaninfo blob receipts file. This will reprocess the blobs again.

When I ran the blob trigger, These folders got created automatically. If the trigger fails, Wait for some time for the folders to get created again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For me there is no blobscaninfo folder at all, and I've waited weeks. On closer inspection the function is throwing a bunch of exceptions (though it's fulfilling it's job so it must be quite late in the process). Can I assume that if the function doesn't succeed then the blobscaninfo folder won't be created?